# When can there be data in both $_GET and $_POST

Tags: php

Is it actually possible to get data in both $_GET and $_POST? And how does this relate to what is in $_REQUEST?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. Consider a form like this:

```
<form action="foobar.php?a=123&b=456" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="a" value="llama">
    <input type="text" name="b" value="duck">
    <input type="submit" name="go" value="Submit me!">
</form>
```

On submitting this form, `$_GET["a"] == "123"`, `$_GET["b"] == "456"`, `$_POST["a"] == "llama"`, `$_POST["b"] == "duck"`, and `$_POST["go"] == "Submit me!"`.

How this relates to the [`$_REQUEST`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.request.php) superglobal depends on the value of the `request_order` (or the older `variables_order`) PHP configuration setting, as [the php.ini documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.request-order) explains.

Comment: so, this gives me the ability to see 123 llamas and 456 ducks without getting up from my desk! cool.

Comment: Happy to help when it comes to llamas and ducks. :)

Answer (score 2):

There can definitely be data in both...  Consider the following (very simple) page:

```
<body>
  <form method="post" action="params.php?myparam=myval">
    <input type="text" name="param1"></input>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
  </form>
</body>
```

Notice that the `action` of the form contains a query string, and the method is `post`.  `$_GET` contains the query string params, `$_POST` contains the form params, and `$_REQUEST` contains the merged parameters from both arrays:

```
array(3) {
  ["myparam"]=>
  string(1) "myval"
  ["param1"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["submit"]=>
  string(6) "submit"
}
```

Check out [`request_order`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.request-order) for controlling how the super-globals are processed in `$_REQUEST`.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible. The `request_order` or (if that's unset) `variables_order` directive determines which will take precedence in `$_REQUEST` when a key is set in both.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible in PHP because, despite their names, $_GET and $_POST don't really need a GET or POST.

- $_GET contains the querystring parsed as form encoded variables.
- $_POST contains the request body parsed as form-encoded variables

It doesn't matter what the actual request method is - it could  be a PUT and those superglobals would still get populated.